# When you import a txt file with lots of lines into SQL Server the application stops responding

Tags: c#, sql-server, import, bigdata

The C# code below reads a `.txt` file containing 1 million rows, this file is a list of articles that I have to import into a SQL Server database.

To do this, I use these steps:

1. Temporary Table Creation
2. Reading the file with insertion in the base database
3. Update of existing articles
4. Insert new articles
5. Temporary table elimination

The problem lies in the fact that after a certain time the import stops and no longer executes the queries, the blocking happens disolito on the updating of the articles already present or on the insertion of the new articles, you have some idea, it is already some time I'm trying to solve this but I can not find the best solution!

How can I improve the performance of this code?

C# code:

```
public static Boolean ImportaListinoElettroveneta(String PercorsoFile)
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Boolean ret = true;

    SqlConnection conn = Database.openconnection();
    String QueryAggiornaNonDisponbili = "Update Articolo set Stato='Nondisponibile' where Importato='ELETTROVENETA' ";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(QueryAggiornaNonDisponbili, conn)
                {
                    CommandTimeout = 0
                };

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    try
    {
        String EliminaTabellaTemporanea = "IF OBJECT_ID('##Importazione') IS not  NULL  drop table ##Importazione";
        command = new SqlCommand(EliminaTabellaTemporanea, conn)
                    {
                        CommandTimeout = 0
                    };

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Errore la tabella temporanea non esiste: " + ex);
    }

    String Query_Creazione_Tabella_Temporanea = "create table ##Importazione( CodiceNumericoEV varchar(5000),DescrizioneArticolo varchar(5000),CodiceArticoloEV varchar(5000),MarcaEV varchar(5000),UM varchar(5000),PrezzoListino money,Sconto1 money,Sconto2 money,Sconto3 money,Sconto4 money,PrezzoNetto money,CodiceBarreMetel bigint,IVA varchar(5000),MarcaMetel varchar(5000),ArticoloMetel varchar(5000),DescrizioneMarca varchar(5000)) ";
    command = new SqlCommand(Query_Creazione_Tabella_Temporanea, conn)
                {
                    CommandTimeout = 0
                };
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command.CommandText = "INSERT Into ##Importazione(CodiceNumericoEV,DescrizioneArticolo,CodiceArticoloEV,MarcaEV,UM,PrezzoListino,Sconto1,Sconto2,Sconto3,Sconto4,PrezzoNetto,CodiceBarreMetel,IVA,MarcaMetel,ArticoloMetel,DescrizioneMarca) Values(@CodiceNumericoEV,@DescrizioneArticolo,@CodiceArticoloEV,@MarcaEV,@UM,@PrezzoListino,@Sconto1,@Sconto2,@Sconto3,@Sconto4,@PrezzoNetto,@CodiceBarreMetel,@IVA,@MarcaMetel,@ArticoloMetel,@DescrizioneMarca)";

    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(PercorsoFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs, System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount("271")))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
            {
                string s;

                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodiceNumericoEV", s.Substring(startIndex: 1, length: 13));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescrizioneArticolo", s.Substring(startIndex: 13, length: 45));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodiceArticoloEV", s.Substring(startIndex: 58, length: 25));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarcaEV", s.Substring(startIndex: 83, length: 6));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UM", s.Substring(startIndex: 89, length: 2));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrezzoListino", decimal.Parse(s.Substring(startIndex: 106, length: 15)));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sconto1", 0);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sconto2", 0);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sconto3", 0);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sconto4", 0);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrezzoNetto", decimal.Parse(s.Substring(startIndex: 142, length: 15)));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodiceBarreMetel", s.Substring(startIndex: 156, length: 13));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IVA", s.Substring(startIndex: 169, length: 2));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarcaMetel", s.Substring(startIndex: 171, length: 3));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticoloMetel", s.Substring(startIndex: 174, length: 16));
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescrizioneMarca", s.Substring(startIndex: 190, length: 25));

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Errore riga: CodiceArticolo:" + s.Substring(startIndex: 174, length: 16) + " tipo di errore: " + ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        command.Parameters.Clear();

        String QueryInserimentoNuoviArticoli = "Insert into Articolo(CodArt,Descrizione,CodMarca,CodEAN,Prezzo,PrezzoListino,UM,Fornitore,Importato) SELECT ArticoloMetel as CodArt,DescrizioneArticolo as Descrizione,MarcaMetel as CodMarca,CodiceBarreMetel as CodEAN,PrezzoNetto,PrezzoListino,UM,MarcaMetel as Fornitore,'ELETTROVENETA' as Importato FROM ##Importazione where ArticoloMetel not in ( select CodArt from Articolo where Importato = 'ELETTROVENETA' ) and MarcaMetel not in ( select CodMarca from Articolo where Importato = 'ELETTROVENETA' ) ";

        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(QueryInserimentoNuoviArticoli, conn)
                    {
                        CommandTimeout = 0
                    };
        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command2.Parameters.Clear();

        String QueryAggiornamentoArticoliPresenti = " Update Articolo set Stato = 'Disponibile', Descrizione = i.Descrizione, CodEAN = i.CodEAN, Prezzo = i.PrezzoNetto, PrezzoListino = i.PrezzoListino, UM = i.UM, DataAggiornamento = getdate() from( SELECT ArticoloMetel as CodArt, DescrizioneArticolo as Descrizione, MarcaMetel as CodMarca, CodiceBarreMetel as CodEAN, PrezzoNetto, PrezzoListino, UM, MarcaMetel as Fornitore, 'ELETTROVENETA' as Importato FROM ##Importazione  where ArticoloMetel in (select CodArt from Articolo where Importato = 'ELETTROVENETA') and MarcaMetel in (select CodMarca from Articolo where Importato = 'ELETTROVENETA'))i where Articolo.CodArt = i.CodArt and i.CodMarca = Articolo.CodMarca and Articolo.Importato = 'ELETTROVENETA' and Articolo.Fornitore = i.Fornitore";

        SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(QueryAggiornamentoArticoliPresenti, conn)
                    {
                        CommandTimeout = 0
                    };
        command3.ExecuteNonQuery();

        try
        {
            String EliminaTabellaTemporanea = "IF OBJECT_ID('##Importazione') IS not  NULL  drop table ##Importazione";
            command = new SqlCommand(EliminaTabellaTemporanea, conn)
                        {
                            CommandTimeout = 0
                        };
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Errore la tabella temporanea non esiste: " + ex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ret = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Errore Importazione Listino Elettroveneta: " + ex);
        Managementerror.SendError("Errore" + ex);
    }

    conn.Close();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: try with small amount of data and see what is consuming too much time so you can improve it.

Comment: @nabukhas
the one that consumes a lot of time are the queries: QueryAggiornamentoArticoliPresenti  and  QueryInserimentoNuoviArticoli

Comment: Why not to import all data then update it?

Comment: @nabukhas I'm doing this now

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are both `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Also worth reading [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry when I said MySql Server I wanted to say SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

I think using procedures or functions in mysql server the response time is going to improve. Always is better doing only the call of the procedures/functions of the BD in your code.

I hope I've helped

Comment: *"using procedures or functions in mysql server"* - typo? This question is tagged sql-server, so mysql is not relevant.